# Form parameters not hashing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

**First**, here is the code: http://pastie.org/5448967

Now, here is the **scenario**:
I have a project object - don't worry about the attachment batches as I have not implemented a solution for those yet - which has associated analysis requests of which there are set options of analyses. That is, there is a table of analyses which the user can choose from and for each one chosen an analysis request is created that links the analysis to the project.

Here's the **problem**:
When attempting to update the analysis requests the first thing that I notice is a problem with the parameters from the form not "hashing" as I would expect.

**Here's what I want**:

```
params={:projects=>{"#{project_id}"=>{project_attribute, project_attribute, etc..., analysisrequests=>[array,of,analysis,ids]}, "#{project_id}"=>{project_attribute, project_attribute, etc..., analysisrequests=>[array,of,analysis,ids]}, ...}
```

**Here's what I get**:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"XfIr7zfVNdlg5HS3Letw4sI/MGNFTtqntQYrgjAh9TY=", "project"=>{"1832"=>{"project_number"=>"261", "nof_samples"=>"5", "analysisrequest"=>{"analysis_id"=>["", "8",
 "12"]}}, "status_id"=>"13", "rush_service"=>"0", "customer_id"=>"111", "project_notes"=>"test", "sample_desc"=>"test", "user_id"=>"1", "quoted_price"=>"1", "1834"=>{"project_number"=>"777", "nof_samples"=>"1", "analysisrequest"=>{"analysis_id"=>["", "3", "9", "20", "22"]}}}, "commit"=>"Submit Changes"}
```

**Stating the obvious**:
I'm not too worried about changing `"analysisrequest"=>{"analysis_id"=>["", "8", ...]}` to `"analysisrequest"=>["", "8", ...]` or `"analysisrequests"=>[]` (note the s). In fact, I've done this so as to render a single multi-select in the form rather than a multi-select for each request associated with the project (which it does if you add the 's') - the "analysis_id" nesting is fine as well as you can see that each request could have `"analysisrequest"=>{"analysis_id"=>[],"project_id"=>[]}` so that's obviously Rails doing its job.

**The most important of my concerns** is that the additional parameters seen after the analysis requests in the first project in the hash are not appearing after the second. That, and, that these additional parameters are not within the hash keyed by "#{project_id}" and, are, instead, outside of it in their own little world. This makes it very difficult for me to update by doing something like:

```
params[:projects].keys.each do |project_id|
'update entries based on project_id'
end
```

Is there anyone out there who might be able to give me some expert advice on this matter? I'm willing to exchange my IT or chemical services for your advice (I work in a lab) because I need to get this up and working.

**Thanks for reading**,
-Adam
*tl;dr* - Form is not "hashing" the attributes in the form in the way that I think it should.

--EDITS--
11/29/2012 - I've still been unable to understand why the parameters hash is being skewed the way it is but, I've come up with a reasonable workaround if I can figure out how to do one thing: configure a delete option via formtastic or my own methods. That is, already through the creation form for a project am I able to create as many analysis requests as needed it's just that now I would need a way to add and remove them through the edit form. I can see an option within the collection being set to "Delete" with the database id working with a method at the controller level; however, what is more pressing is being able to add additional requests in the form which I have not yet been able to achieve via Rails 3.2.1. I know that it works in 2.3.5 but, so far, it hasn't been working for my configuration. I'll post more as I find out.

+2 hours (later) - Implemented Ryan Bates' ep.197 methods for removing fields so far; but, I've run into some kind of gotcha where either formtastic or my model has no idea what to do with the _destroy field even though I set the :allow_destroy => true. Perhaps it has to do with the placement of the link? Here's the code for my newest form (the js and application helper code are as they can be seen [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)): http://pastie.org/5454653

Comment: The keys that are on "wrong level", are they columns for the same model/table as the correct ones? In that case I would have moved the fields in the view that are on "wrong level" to before `fields_for :analysisrequest`, to see if they then will get in the "right level". Just as a first step in finding the error - unless someone else comes up with a good answer

Comment: Yes, those attributes are columns for the same project model that has the fields_for (analysisrequest) attributes. I thought about this myself but I don't think that it would solve it.

Comment: I didn't mean to solve it, only to start with something and try to figure out what is causing the problem (it's how I normally do).

Comment: I can see how that might solve the problem; however, I don't want to admit it because that would really put a dent in my faith in Rails previously just taking care of everything for me haha.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Perhaps you should have these routes:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get 'edit', action: 'edit_collection'
    put 'update_collection'
  end
end
```

Don't forget to define a `update_collection` method in the controller.

Just a note you can use class instances in edit_collection.html.erb instead of rendering the page and passing in the local.

For instance:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
```

instead of

```
<% for project in projects %>
```

Comment: I'll update the pastie with the routes and you'll see that I have those. I also thought about doing what you suggested but didn't think it would make much of a difference. I'll give it a shot but I'm still skeptical. Thank you though and I hope you'll stick around to "hash" this out: HA!